# How to retrive data from nested JSON using API call and display it on a webpage using js

Tags: javascript, json

I can only fetch and display JSON content from the first field can't access any other fields.

I can only fetch **ua** from the first the JSON field can't fetch **family** from the second JSON field.

It is giving an error in the console tab

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of
> null at getData

**js Code**

```
<script>
       function myFunction() {
        var x = navigator.userAgent;
        const newText = x.split(/\s/).join('');
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
        const text = document.getElementById('demo').textContent;
         const api_url = 'http://api.userstack.com/detect?access_key=<key>&ua=';
           async function getData() {
            const response = await fetch(api_url + newText);
            const data = await response.json();
            const { ua,  family} = data;
            document.getElementById('ua').textContent = ua;
            document.getElementById('family').textContent = os;
       }
       getData();
       }
</script>
```

**JSON**

```
{
  "ua":"browser agent",
  "type":"browser",
  "brand":null,
  "name":null,
  "url":"https:\/\/about.google\/",
  "os":{
    "name":"Windows 10",
    "code":"windows_10",
    "url":"https:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Windows_10",
    "family":"Windows",
    "family_code":"windows",
    "family_vendor":"Microsoft Corporation.",
    "icon":"https:\/\/assets.userstack.com\/icon\/os\/windows10.png",
    "icon_large":"https:\/\/assets.userstack.com\/icon\/os\/windows10_big.png"
  },
  "device":{
    "is_mobile_device":false,
    "type":"desktop",
    "brand":null,
    "brand_code":null,
    "brand_url":null,
    "name":null
  },
  "browser":{
    "name":"Chrome",
    "version":"82.0",
    "version_major":"92",
    "engine":"WebKit\/Blink"
  },
  "crawler":{
    "is_crawler":false,
    "category":null,
    "last_seen":null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

family is not a direct child of data, so

```
const { ua,  family} = data;
```

won't work (and you will see an error in the console).  try

```
const { ua,  os: {family} } = data;
```

(More details on destructuring nested objects [here](https://medium.com/@pyrolistical/destructuring-nested-objects-9dabdd01a3b8)

Additionally you have:

```
document.getElementById('family').textContent = os;
```

However `os` is undefined.  You probably mean

```
document.getElementById('family').textContent = family;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access `family` directly, but it is a property of `os`. So you must be altering the const to:

```js
const { ua,  os:{family}} = ans;
```